# Why do I need to clear the screen even if I intend to overwrite every single pixel?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

In the SDL2 documentation it is mentioned that :

> You are strongly encouraged to call SDL_RenderClear() to initialize the backbuffer before starting each new frame's drawing, even if you plan to overwrite every pixel.

What is the reason behind that? Isn't it just a useless call to fill the screen one particular color when you know you're going to overwrite it anyway?

Comment: what about drawing something with transparency? you'll get the "old" screen leaking through.

Comment: @MarcB Not if there's a fully opaque backdrop, which I believe OP might have.

Comment: "strongly encouraged" != "need to". You decide what you need to achieve whatever it is you wanted. In theory it may be easier for implementation to discard old buffer, but I've never seen that in practice (on the contrary - some OpenGL implementations just draw solid quad to 'clear' under the hood). But why you don't want to do it so much?

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation you are referring to. I didn't found this in the wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* to call `SDL_RenderClear()` in every frame if you are updating every pixel. You can even make some nice effects by using semi-transparent pixels (e.g, "motion blur" by painting a black semi-transparent rectangle before painting another frame).

If this is just your own code, yeah, it might seem useless, but you knever know once your code is in the hands of someone else. They might use different images, things that are transparent and they're going to have a hard time figuring out why everything is repeated in the screen.

Thats one good reason to be *encouraged* to clear the screen. You are not required to do so. Also, its worth noting that *clearing* the screen with a color is different than *filling* the screen with a color by painting every pixel (and a lot faster), thus, your performance lost is neglible compared to the potential future headache.

You can check the `RenderClear` code for every platform and see how it does different things to do what you said (*fill* the screen with a color), but with clear *method* rather than paint *method*:

- [SW_RenderClear](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/50ffb2b7ee1c/src/render/software/SDL_render_sw.c#l383)
- [PSP_RenderClear](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/50ffb2b7ee1c/src/render/psp/SDL_render_psp.c#l636)
- [GLES2_RenderClear](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/50ffb2b7ee1c/src/render/opengles2/SDL_render_gles2.c#l1295)
- [GLES_RenderClear](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/50ffb2b7ee1c/src/render/opengles/SDL_render_gles.c#l809)
- [GL_RenderClear](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/50ffb2b7ee1c/src/render/opengl/SDL_render_gl.c#l1137)
- [D3D11_RenderClear](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/50ffb2b7ee1c/src/render/direct3d11/SDL_render_d3d11.c#l2332)
- [D3D_RenderClear](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/50ffb2b7ee1c/src/render/direct3d/SDL_render_d3d.c#l1291)

You can see that the only implementation of `SDL_RenderClear` that actually fills the screen is the `SW_RenderClear` one, but other than that, there is no harm in clearing the screen, but no obligation either. SDL works just fine without it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that you will draw over every pixel with a fully nontransparent color you don't need to use SDL_RenderClear().

SDL_RenderClear() is for when you you have a backround color in your frame thats actual visible.